# File types.d.ts is not a module

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I'm working on creating a npm package and I've got the source code pretty much done. I've been testing it locally before I publish and I'm getting two error with typescript. `File '<path>/McStatus.d.ts' is not a module.` and `Cannot find name 'McServer'`.

My package has a `src` folder with `index.ts` and `types.d.ts`. In the root of the package I have `McStatus.d.ts`.

### Code Snippets:

package.json:

```
"main": "dist/index.js",
"types": "McStatus.d.ts",
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

src/index.ts

```js
export function checkStatus(server: McServer): Promise<Status> {
  ...
}
```

McStatus.d.ts

```
declare namespace McStatus {
  function checkStatus(server: McServer): Promise<Status>

  interface Status {
    ping?: number
    version?: string
    motd?: string
    players?: number
    max_players?: number
  }

  interface McServer {
    host: string
    port: number
  }
}
```

### Testing package:

I created a testing directory and I've tried `npm install <path to package>`, `npm link`, and even `npm pack` and installing the `.tgz` file.

My testing file is where the errors come from

```
import checkStatus from 'mcstatus'
// File '/home/stphn/git/mcstatus/McStatus.d.ts' is not a module.

const options: McServer = {
// Cannot find name 'McServer'
  host: "mc.stephenduvall.me",
  port: 25565,
}

checkStatus(options).then(console.log).catch(console.log)
```

Comment: I would suggest putting the types in `index.ts` and setting the `declaration: true` option in your `tsconfig.json` to generate `.d.ts` files when you build the project: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: Same issue. If i declare it in typings, it works, but I want the types to be visible to the other developers